# TextView text is not updated

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to change `TextView` text in one `fragment` from another `fragment`.
I have tried to do this by communicating with the activity.
But, what I noticed was that the `TextView` text is changed yet it doesn't appear with the new text.

I have `ProductFragment` which contains `listview` of products categories. and when an `onItemClick()` in the list is performed I try to show the `SecondFragment` which contains only `TextView`. I then try to update the text for the category that was clicked in the `listview` in the `ProductFragment`. `MainActivity` is the `FragmentActivity`.

Here is my code:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
private TextView tv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);
    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_second_fragment);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

public void setTextViewText(CharSequence text){
    tv.setText(text);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}//The toast shows the correct text but its not updated in the fragment (on the emulator)
```

The relevant code in the ProductFragment

```
    @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.onDataActivity = (OnDataPass)activity;
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), products.get(position).getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    onDataActivity.loadItemsForCategory(products.get(position).getName().toString());
}
```

and in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnKeyListener, OnDataPass{

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction ft;


    private ProductsFragment productsFragment;
    private SecondFragment secondFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        productsFragment = ProductsFragment.newInstance(products);
        secondFragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, secondFragment).commit();

    @Override
    public void loadItemsForCategory(String category) {
        secondFragment.setTextViewText("Requseted to show items for " + category);
        ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, secondFragment).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: call `setTextViewText` in your `onCreateView` of `SecondFragment`

Comment: first you need to check if the fragment is visible then set the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it after you replace fragments:

```
@Override
public void loadItemsForCategory(String category) {
    ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, secondFragment).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
    secondFragment.setTextViewText("Requseted to show items for " + category);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
private TextView tv;
private String text="";    
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);
    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_second_fragment);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    tv.setText(text);
}

public void setTextViewText(CharSequence text){
    this.text=text;
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: try my edited ans what Raghunandan said is right u need to wait until view is appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

You need to make sure the fragment is attached.

In `loadItemsForCategory`

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key",category);           
FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
secondFragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container,secondFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Then in onCreateview of second fragment

```
String strtext = getArguments().getString("key");
```

Call

```
setTextViewText(strtext)
```